# Need to remove blanks from dataframe while keeping cell values containing the string "NA"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe being imported from ftp, for which i need to trim and only show those rows where one or more of the 32 columns have blank cells, as this then needs sending back to have our admin team fill in the missing data.

I am able to do this using the isna() method
However, in one of the columns "management population" one of the correct values is the string "NA" so of course isna() is also reading TRUE for the cells that contain "NA" and I need to find a way to stop this happening and preserve instances of the string "NA".
Grateful for any ideas

Comment: please provide your code (or even better a minimal reproducible example). The string `NA` should not return True using `isna()` so there might be a problem in how you are constructing the dataframe

Comment: Looking at the dataframe (created using read_csv it looks like the issue is that step skipping the "NA" in the raw data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, it was not the isna() but instead the default behaviour of read_csv that was causing the issue.
So I created a list to store the values I need Pandas to see as NaN:

```
myNAValues = ['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A N/A',
            '#N/A', 'N/A', 'n/a', '', '#NA', 'NULL', 'null', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan', '']
```

And then amended the read_csv to include:
`keep_default_na=False, na_values=myNAValues`

And now the output is as I needed